# Viewing Details from View Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

I'm trying to figure out how to use a ViewModel to view details in a view.

I have a view model set up but can't seem to use it in my views.

In my controller I have a Details method that I want to use to display all the details in the ViewModel.

So far I am passing in a username as a string and then creating a new instance of the ViewModel, I am then trying to populate the ViewModel with data but am not sure how I need to do this. I am assigning the username based on the id coming in -

```
public ViewResult Details(string id)
        {

            var viewModel = new RegisterViewModel();
            viewModel.UserName = id;
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

and then sending the viewModel back to the view, but how do I get the other related data into the viewModel??

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What do you mean by *get the other related data*? Do you mean from inside the view?

Comment: I mean from the models. The view model contains both user and userdetails models. When I click on the 'detail;s' link I want to retrieve all the data for that particular user, but I'm unsure how to do that. And I mean related to the UserName that is passed in. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is query your database and pull the related information into your view model before passing it back to your view i.e.

```
public ViewResult Details(string id)
{
    var entity = // pull record from DB by id
    return View(new RegisterViewModel()
    {
        UserName = id,
        AnotherProperty = entity.AnotherProperty
        ...
    });
}
```

If your mapping view models to models in a lot of places you might want to consider using [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper), it will simplify your code.

Comment: Thanks - So would entity be an individual model? Would I need to declare an entity for each model in my ViewModel?

Comment: @MartinMcMahon As you have tagged your question EF I assume you have an EF model? i.e. you have generated an EDMX file from your database. The "*entity*" would refer to your actual EF entity (the record pulled from the database).